# How can I exit from a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
function refreshGrid(entity) {
    var store = window.localStorage;
    var partitionKey;
    ...
    ...
```

I would like to exit from this function if an "if" condition is met. How can I exit? Can I just say break, exit or return?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

```
if ( condition ) {
    return;
}
```

The `return` exits the function returning `undefined`.

The `exit` statement doesn't exist in javascript.

The `break` statement allows you to exit a *loop*, not a function. For example:

```
var i = 0;
while ( i < 10 ) {
    i++;
    if ( i === 5 ) {
        break;
    }
}
```

This also works with the `for` and the `switch` loops.

Answer (score 19):

Use return statement anywhere you want to exit from function.

```
if(somecondtion)
   return;

if(somecondtion)
   return false;
```

Answer (score 7):

you can use

`return false;` or `return;` within your condition.

```
function refreshGrid(entity) {
    var store = window.localStorage;
    var partitionKey;
    ....
    if(some_condition) {
      return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Use this when if satisfies**

do

```
return true;
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use return as in:

```
function refreshGrid(entity) {
  var store = window.localStorage;
  var partitionKey;
  if (exit) {
    return;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in Google App Scripts, and solved it like the rest said, but with a little more..

```
function refreshGrid(entity) {
var store = window.localStorage;
var partitionKey;
if (condition) {
  return Browser.msgBox("something");
  }
}
```

This way you not only exit the function, but show a message saying why it stopped. Hope it helps.