# exit a function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I created a draggable item with the draggable ui. Now, when dragging over a specific element I want to trigger a function `startSwipe()`. Untill here all goes well... But after I stop dragging, the function stays active and each time I hover the element again the function triggers again.

I did some research, and come across this question  [How can I exit from a javascript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459207/how-can-i-exit-from-a-javascript-function)

But I'm having a hard time to implement it in my stuff.

Here are the code:

```
function startDragging() {

    var $calendar = $(".calendar-tasks");

    $("li.allowed-to-drag", $calendar).draggable({

        revert: "invalid",
        helper: function (event, ui) {

            return $("<div class='task-image' style='z-index: 10000;'><span class='icon-pushpin'></span></div>").appendTo("body");

        },
        cursorAt: { left: 25 },
        zIndex: 100,
        start: function (event) {

            $(".previous-week a, .next-week a, .previous-month a, .next-month a").addClass("swipeable");

            startSwipe();

        },
        stop: function (event) {

            $(".previous-week a, .next-week a, .previous-month a, .next-month a").removeClass("swipeable");

            stopSwipe(); // A test if this would work...

        }

    });

}

function startSwipe() {

    $(".previous-week a, .next-week a, .previous-month a, .next-month a").mouseover(function(){

        console.log("hovered");

    });

    return;

}

function stopSwipe() {

    return;

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/amvk45nh/2/

Comment: Have you tried `return false`?

Comment: I've tried it both in the function `stopSwipe()` and `startSwipe()`

Comment: can you please create a fiddle

Comment: `stopSwipe()` is empty...perhaps you should comment that out until you know for sure if you need such a function rather than have the stopping mechanism within the `startSwipe()` function. Unfortunately, any advice is conjecture until we can see a "working" example as @ShekharPankaj has already requested.

Comment: Currently creating the fiddle ;)

Comment: Downvoter please tell why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the `startSwipe()` function you are binding an event, so you should unbind it when you want it to stop. You could try this:

```
function stopSwipe() {

    $(".previous-week a, .next-week a, .previous-month a, .next-month a").unbind('mouseover');

}
```