# How to exit in the middle of a function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function

How about nested if?

```
$scope.addToCart = function () {
    if (flagA) {
        if (flagB) {
            if (flagC) {
                alert('nononono!');
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    someAnotherFunction();
};
```

---

I have a function:

```
$scope.addToCart = function () {
    var foo = 5;
    if (someFlag == 'Y') {
        alert('warning!');
        return;
    }
    someAnotherFunction();
};
```

I invoke this function somewhere

```
ng-click = "addToCart()"
```

My intention is to exit this function if

```
someFlag == 'Y'
```

then not to execute

```
someAnotherFunction();
```

But it still execute it.

WebStorm tell me this `return` is unnecessary so it could be safely removed.

Comment: `if (someFlag == 'Y') {` condition must be failing. Are you getting alert?

Comment: Yes the alert worked.

Comment: Unexpected behaviour is usually what happens when code relies on global variables.

Comment: @Mladen Ilić the `someFlag` is get from an API

Comment: @untmat [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459207/how-can-i-exit-from-a-javascript-function?noredirect=1&lq=1) answer says break could exit a loop not a function.

Comment: The current answers recommend to use an `else` block. While that will likely solve your problem, it's impossible that anything after the `return` statement is executed in the first place. You should figure out what the actual issue with your code is, not work around it.

Comment: Could you post more code? Specifically where `someFlag` is set?

Comment: Your posted code works just fine: https://repl.it/Crm9

Comment: It is more likely that the `$scope.addToCart()` function is being called again (after `someFlag` has changed), or that `someAnotherFunction()` is being called from somewhere else, than it is that the `return` statement is not being executed immediately after the `alert()`.

Comment: In response to nested ifs: if you just want to check conditions and do nothing else in the if blocks, `if (flagA && flagB && flagC) {...}`. The workaround proposed in the answers has the limitations, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820839/using-return-instead-of-else-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that the if condition is satisfied, but return isn't working, then you can also try putting `someAnotherFunction();` into else:

```
if (someFlag == 'Y') {
    alert('warning!');
    return;
}
else {
    someAnotherFunction();
}
```

That way `someAnotherFunction()` can be executed only if the if block isn't.

**Addendum**

The original code should work and this is just a workaround, as pointed out in the comment. However both methods achieve the same goal in theory.

For more details, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820839/using-return-instead-of-else-in-javascript) - for details on the differences.

Comment: `if` is not a loop. And while this is a good workaround, the original code should work just fine.

Comment: I meant block, not loop, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the call to the other function in the else-block:

```
$scope.addToCart = function () {
    var foo = 5;
    if (someFlag == 'Y') {
        alert('warning!');
        return;
    } else {
      someAnotherFunction();
    }

};
```

That should take you closer to understanding what is going on